# Why does the div following a floated div overlap the floated one?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-float

I have a floated left sidebar layout with breadcrumbs and main content area on the right.

If you Inspect Element on the breadcrumbsContainer (see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LCdwV/2/)), you can see that its left edge is all the way at the left edge of the browser window, but I expected it would be at the right edge of the sidebar.

I see that there are several other similar questions, but I haven't been able to find one yet with the same issue or an answer.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div class="menuItem">Users</div>
        <div class="menuItem">Settings</div>
    </div>
    <div class="breadcrumbsContainer">
        Breadcrumbs go here
    </div>
    <div class="main">
    Main content goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}

.menuItem {
    height: 60px;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    background: lightBlue;
}

.breadcrumbsContainer {
    height: 24px;
    background: lightGrey;
}

.main {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

### jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/LCdwV/2/

### Notes

- The following .main div is positioned as I expected.
- While simplifying the situation for my jsfiddle, I discovered that removing the overflow:scroll from the .main div caused it to behave like the breadcrumbsContainer.
- Conversely, adding overflow:scroll (overflow:hidden) to the breadcrumbsContainer caused its bounding box to adjust to where I expected it to be.

### Questions

1. Why does the bounding box of breadcrumbsContainer not start where I expect, and yet the text contained in the breadcrumbsContainer is pretty much where I expect it to be?
2. What is the "right way" to setup a layout like this so that the breadcrumbsContainer and .main div don't overlap the sidebar, but also resize as the browser window resizes?

I could do it easily with absolute positioning and the jQuery resize() event, but it seems like it should be possible without that.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd use absolute positioning for this kind of layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code and here's my solution:

you cannot let the next div after you had a float: left rule to not having float rule. for example like your next div class is breadCrumbsContainer. It has no float rule.
So, you need to define float: left for .breadCrumbsContainer and main. But there is an issue with the width of the div, it will fits to its content.

I recommend you to add your layouting rule first. so it looks like this :

```
#sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}

.menuItem {
    height: 60px;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    background: lightBlue;
}

.breadcrumbsContainer {
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
    height: 24px;
    background: lightGrey;
}

.main {
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Otherwise, you can also set your sidebar position to be absolute and you can create a div to wrap your main content

CSS :

```
#sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
}
.main-container{
    position: relative;
    left: 200px;
}
.menuItem {
    height: 60px;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    background: lightBlue;
}

.breadcrumbsContainer {
    height: 24px;
    background: lightGrey;
}

.main {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div class="menuItem">Users</div>
        <div class="menuItem">Settings</div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="breadcrumbsContainer">
            Breadcrumbs go here
        </div>
        <div class="main">
        Main content goes here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's very recommended to look at [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) framework

Comment: Your second example behaves as I would like.  I would prefer a fixed-width sidebar.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap for some things (tables, buttons), but I haven't found a way to replicate this layout.  This is my first Bootstrap project though, so I'm still getting up to speed.

Comment: You can do nested grid if needed. For example you have <div class='row><div class='col-md4'> already, you can add <div class='row><div class='col-md4'> again inside it. Grid width rule is count by percentage from the parent DOM

Answer (score 2):

`float` removes an element from the normal flow, meaning that neighboring elements are positioned as if the float didn't exist (which is why `.breadcrumb-container` is overlapping .. it ignores the box of its sibling).

This isn't the case if an element has an inline display.

Since the text is inline, it respects the presence of this float, and thus is placed flush against its right edge - this is the intended behaviour since text was meant to wrap around floated elements.

Comment: Thanks, that answers the part about why the text behaves differently.

Answer (score 1):

Because its still anchored or positioned to the left edge of the window, but the div itself or content does not begin until after the sidebar. The scroll behavior is what is differentiating the two when you inspect it as the scroll bars force the document to say that the dive does not sock all the way to the left. Basically you are getting the correct functionality, you have just reach upon one of the oddities of css

Comment: Setting overflow:hidden also has the same effect, so it's not the scroll bars specifically.  I'm thinking that it considers the part of breadcrumbsContainer under the floated div as an overflow area, and so trims it away.